# Copying Data from one Sheet to another using Check Boxes

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to figure out a way to "automate" a task in google sheets. I have a data model that lists all the data on one sheet of all the 'hit percentages' of sports props. The data changes as games complete. I'd like to have check boxes(or something similar) next to the rows that when it's checked it copies that row and then adds it into a sheet called 'Logs" after the last row.

I put this sheet together as an example:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KocfnKXK1sPmBr3uQfcn8dC6MYV0JUWDz5Ql3AgTMEI/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- When you checked the checkbox of column "B" of "Changing Data" sheet, you want to copy the row to the next row of the last row of "Log" sheet.

In this case, how about the following modification? In this modification, in order to check whether the checkbox is checked, the simple trigger of OnEdit is used.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet and save the script. When you use this script, please check the checkbox of column "B" of "Changing Data" sheet. By this, the script is automatically run by the OnEdit trigger.

```js
function onEdit(e) {
  const srcSheetName = "Changing Data"; // This is from your sample Spreadsheet.
  const dstSheetName = "Log"; // This is from your sample Spreadsheet.

  const { range, source } = e;
  const sheet = range.getSheet();
  if (sheet.getSheetName() != srcSheetName || range.columnStart != 2 || !range.isChecked()) return;
  const dstSheet = source.getSheetByName(dstSheetName);
  range.offset(0, -1, 1, 2).copyTo(dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1));
}
```

#### Reference:

- [Simple Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers)

Comment: Thank you @Tanaike - it does exactly as asked for.  

now I ran into another issue. Since my Data Set contains vlookup's in some of the cells in a row, it copies the formula to Logs which naturally shoots off errors. Is it possible to copy just the readable text displayed in each cell in the row?

Comment: @TooTallDerr Thank you for replying. About `Is it possible to copy just the readable text displayed in each cell in the row?`, in this case, how about modifying `range.offset(0, -1, 1, 2).copyTo(dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1))` to `range.offset(0, -1, 1, 2).copyTo(dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1), {contentsOnly:true})` or `range.offset(0, -1, 1).copyTo(dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1), {contentsOnly:true})`?

Comment: @TooTallDerr For example, when `the readable text displayed in each cell in the row` includes the columns except for the column "A" and "B", please modify it to `range.offset(0, -1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).copyTo(dstSheet.getRange(dstSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1), { contentsOnly: true })`, and test it again.

Answer (score 2):

#### Copy Row To Log Sheet

```
function onEdit(e) {
  //e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 7 && e.range.rowStart > 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
    //e.source.toast("Gate1");
    e.source.toast("Gate1"); 
    const lsh = e.source.getSheetByName("Log");
    const vs = sh.getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
    lsh.getRange(lsh.getLastRow() + 1, 1,vs.length,vs[0].length).setValues(vs);
  }
}
```

Sheet0:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Alternative Solution

You can try this another implementation using [appendRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#appendrowrowcontents) & [getValue()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalue) methods.

This sample will only run the `onEdit()` function when `column B` check-boxes are selected on the `Changing Data` sheet. The function will only copy the `text` on `Column A` row that is adjacent to the selected checkbox.

## Script

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'Changing Data' && e.range.getColumn() == 2 && e.value == "TRUE" ? e.source.getSheetByName('Log').appendRow([e.source.getSheetByName('Changing Data').getRange('A' + e.range.getRow()).getValue()]) : _ ;
}
```

> ***Alternate Script*** if you want to include check-boxes to be also copied:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.getActiveSheet().getName() == 'Changing Data' && e.range.getColumn() == 2 && e.value == "TRUE" ?
    (e.source.getSheetByName('Log').appendRow([e.source.getSheetByName('Changing Data').getRange('A' + e.range.getRow()).getValue()]) ?
      (e.source.getSheetByName('Changing Data').getRange('B' + e.range.getRow()).copyTo(e.source.getSheetByName('Log').getRange('B' + e.source.getSheetByName('Log').getLastRow()))) : _) : _;
}
```

## Demo

> `Changing Data` sheet

- [image]

> `Logs` sheet

- [image]

Comment: @TooTallDerr Hope this one helps you too.